# Lua string::byte() returns nil in LuaJit 2.1.0-beta3

Tags: lua, luajit

I didn't have this problem on **LuaJit 2.1.0-beta2** but due to reasons had to update to **beta3**. Following code at some point generates an error on the line where "**string.char(byte)**" is called.

> "bad argument #1 to ‘char’ (number expected, got nil)"

```
function convert_to_null_terminated_string(data, offset, len)
  if data:len() < (offset + len - 1) then
      print("Data len " .. data:len() .. " < (offset+len-1) " .. (offset + len - 1))
      return nil
  end
  local output = {}

  for i = 0, len - 1 do
      local byte = data:byte(offset + i)
      if byte == 0 then break end
      table.insert(output, string.char(byte))
  end

  return table.concat(output, "")
```

Documentation about **string:byte()** doesn't mention it is possible that the function would return nil and I am sure I am within the boundaries of the string as the check is done in the function before calling **string:byte().**

It is worth mentioning that I compiled LuaJit with **x64_GC** flag to have a possibility to allocate more than 1-2GB of the memory in the Lua. All the code is running inside of the docker image based on Ubuntu 16 on Amazon Linux 2 host.

Does it looks like I am facing a bug in LuaJit?

Comment: This bug might already have fixed.  Test with newest version (from git HEAD) instead of using obsolete beta3.

Comment: How about printing `#data`, `offset` and `len` as well as printing `i` and `offset+i` in every iteration just to see what exactly happens? Printing `data:sub(offset+1, offset+1)` might also help.

Comment: The print() function never executed on the environment where the issue reproduces so I suppose 'data:len() is always >= (offset + len - 1)' and I can't put print() for every function call because this function is called million times per day. 

Is that possible that local output = {} results in nil output variable? Might be when the RAM memory is exhausted?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I see there is v2.1 branch. But LUAJIT_ENABLE_GC64 isn't available on that branch.

Comment: GC64 is enabled by default now.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Good suggestion. The issue isn't reproducible anymore on current HEAD of v2.1 branch.